# VM VirtualBox, Ubuntu 9.10: USB memory stick and SD card not detected

Tags: virtualbox, usb, ubuntu-9.10, virtual-machines

I have installed Ubuntu9.10 on VM VirtualBox, on my HP laptop. My laptop has several USB ports and also a SD card port. Unfortunately, I'm unable to access both, my **pen-drive on the USB port** and my **8GB SD card** inserted in the SD Card port. Can anyone suggest me what I should do for my Ubuntu to detect both of them?

I have installed all latest updates on Ubuntu. I'm able to use my USB mouse.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the Sun/Oracle VirtualBox or the OSE version? Only the official version has direct USB support - the mouse support will be from the host OS.

Right-click on the USB icon:

[image: virtualbox tray usb icon]

and select the device there.

Comment: I'm using Oracle VM Virtual Box.

Comment: Sorry Andrew, I'm unable to see any devices getting listed in that to select. Moreover, I would like to see the devices I add getting recognized my Ubuntu. For my future I would like to burn a Ubuntu ISO into my SD Card.

Answer (score 1):

When you are unable to pass USB-slots trough to the VM, or you get the error `Failed to access the USB subsystem`, you should add the user to the group `vboxusers` like this:

```
usermod -aG vboxusers username
```